# Laravel - Method Illuminate\\Support\\Collection::makeHidden does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent, laravel-8

I want to hide the columns `password` & `OTP` ,that is included in `$uses` result. Actually these 2 columns are part of the `users` table.  I've tried like below. But it generates the error - `Method Illuminate\\Support\\Collection::makeHidden does not exist` . How to solve this? Any suggestions..

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('location', 'users.id', '=', 'location.id')
            ->join('user_technical_details', 'users.id', '=', 'user_technical_details.id')
            ->get();
$d=$users->makeHidden(['password','OTP']);    
return response()->json([
            'message' => 'profile viewed successfully',
            'data' => $d,
            'statusCode' => 200,
            'status' => 'success'],200);
```

Comment: `makeHidden()` is a method of eloquent, not query builder. You can `select()` your query, then it will be visibled only selected column. `->select('id','name')->get()` or `->get(['id','name'])`

Comment: What is the version of Laravel you're using? `makeHidden()` exists from **v5.8**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to execute this method on the collection but it's a model method:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->join('location', 'users.id', '=', 'location.id')
            ->join('user_technical_details', 'users.id', '=', 'user_technical_details.id')
            ->get();
foreach($users as $user) {
    $user->makeHidden(['password','OTP']);
}
```

And this still doesn't work since you're using `DB::table('users')` over `Users::all()`.

---

In order to use a model, you have to do the following:

model:

```
class User extends Model
{
    // Instead of `makeHidden()` you can do this if you want them always to be hidden
    // protected $hidden = ['password','OTP'];

    public function location()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(App\Models\Location::class, 'users.id', '=', 'location.id');
    }

    public function technical_details()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(App\Models\UserTechnicalDetail::class, 'users.id', '=', 'user_technical_details.id');
    }
}
```

controller:

```
$users = Users::with(['location', 'technical_details'])
            ->get();
foreach($users as $user) {
    $user->makeHidden(['password','OTP']);
}
```

Comment: I tried this in my controller . `Call to undefined method stdClass::makeHidden()` - got this error

Comment: Oh, wait. You don't have a model. Are you sure, you want to use `DB::table('users')` over `Users::all()`?

Comment: My ultimate need is that i need to join 3 tables : `users`,`location`,`user_technical_details` and want to hide the `password` & `OTP` columns in the `users` table. Can use any methods. using `DB::table('users')` or `Users::all()` is fine. Through any methods, i want to attain this result

Comment: can u tell me a solution for this?

Comment: Sure. Updated my question. You probably still have to adjust a few things.

Comment: @shaedrich It's a `Collection` class method and will not work on `Model` class object

Comment: I know. That's why I updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest solution for your case:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
        ->join('location', 'users.id', '=', 'location.id')
        ->join('user_technical_details', 'users.id', '=', 'user_technical_details.id')
        ->get()
        ->map(function ($user) {
            unset($user->password);
            unset($user->OTP);
            reurn $user;
        });
```

I'd recommend to use Eloquent Relationships instead of joins for better abstraction:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 2):

In order to get User object from db, you should use User Model:

```
$users = User::query()
            ->join('location', 'users.id', '=', 'location.id')
            ->join('user_technical_details', 'users.id', '=', 'user_technical_details.id')
            ->get();
foreach($users as $user) {
    $user->makeHidden(['password','OTP']);
}
```

Comment: `makeHidden()` is a `Collection` method, it won't work on `Model`

Comment: it 'is for both collection and model

Comment: model:https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HidesAttributes.html#method_makeHidden

Comment: collection:https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_makeHidden

Comment: Weird, PHPStorm editor showing it's a method only for `Collection` not for `Model` class

Comment: I have just test it in php  storm 2020.3.1 it works just fine, something like:   $user=User::first();
        $user->makeHidden(['']);

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party, sorry.
I had the same issue. I wanted to exclude created_at and updated_at columns from my SQL result (using DB:Table, not specific eloquent models). The makeHidden function "does not exist". NoOorz24 has a similar answer to mine, but instead, I did this (which is useful if you're running a slightly old version of PHP). It's a bit more processor hungry but it did the job.

```
 $content = DB::table($talbename)->get();
 foreach($content as $c) {
     unset($c->created_at);
     unset($c->updated_at);
 }
```